# Meteor Leaderboard example: resetting the scores

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I've been trying to do Meteor's leaderboard example, and I'm stuck at the second exercise, resetting the scores. So far, the furthest I've got is this:

```
// On server startup, create some players if the database is empty.
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace",
                   "Grace Hopper",
                   "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
                   "Nikola Tesla",
                   "Claude Shannon"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Players.insert({name: names[i]}, {score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5});
    }
});
Meteor.methods({
  whymanwhy: function(){
    Players.update({},{score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5});
  },
}
)};
```

And then to use the whymanwhy method I have a section like this in if(Meteor.isClient)

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input#resetscore': function(){Meteor.call("whymanwhy");    }
});
```

The problem with this is that {} is supposed to select all the documents in MongoDB collection, but instead it creates a new blank scientist with a random score. Why? {} is supposed to select everything. I tried "_id" : { $exists : true }, but it's a kludge, I think. Plus it behaved the same as {}.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? The meteor webpage says:

> Make a button that resets everyone's score to a random number. (There
>   is already code to do this in the server startup code. Can you factor
>   some of this code out and have it run on both the client and the
>   server?)

Well, to run this on the client first, instead of using a method to the server and having the results pushed back to the client, I would need to explicitly specify the _ids of each document in the collection, otherwise I will run into the "Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]". But how can I get that? Or should I just make it easy and use collection.allow()? Or is that the only way?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing two things:

1. you need to pass the option, `{multi: true}`, to update or it will only ever change one record.
2. if you only want to change some fields of a document you need to use `$set`.  Otherwise update assumes you are providing the complete new document you want and replaces the original.

So I think the correct function is:

```
Players.update({},{$set: {score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5}}, {multi:true});
```

The [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#update) on this is pretty thorough.